linkcolor= command not changing color for links
I was trying to change the color of my href formatting for blue for the text, from the default red. Here is my sample file:
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[hyperindex,hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyperindex,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\title{Test hyperref}
\section{Test of hyperref formatting}
This has an hyperref \href{https://www.google.com}{JIRA-2670}.
\end{document}


The link text still shows up as the default red. Is there something else I have to change?
Any help or tips is greatly appreciated!
Russ

you have an url, so you need urlcolor=blue.

Thank you! That did the trick! Thx!!
